# Create a enum/structure of strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, struct, enums

Good afternoon,

I am looking for a way to instantiate and define a bunch of different string variables in c++ and to group them into a data structure, much like an enum data type, but with strings.

Is there a good way to do this in C++, I am not looking to create an array of strings, instead I want each to have an individual name, as well as a parent data structure.

This is what I am trying to accomplish

```
somestructuretype MyData {
    string alpha = "this is string A";
    string bravo = "this is string B";
    string charlie = "this is string C";
};
```

So that I can call these strings somewhat like this:

string temp = MyData.alpha;

I know this is possible in c#, is this possible in C++

Thanks,
-D

Comment: do you need to pass them around together (for instance, if you plan to have several similar structs with different values for their fields)?

Answer (score 4):

I believe what your looking for is a way to organize a group of related strings. Instead of looking for data structures, you could consider using a namespace.

Example:

```
namespace MyData {
    static const string alpha = "this is string A";
    static const string bravo = "this is string B";
    static const string charlie = "this is string C";
};
```

You would access it like:

```
string temp = MyData::alpha;
```

Comment: +1 It's noteworthy that the `static` approach illustrated is great when the strings are to be used in a single translation unit, but if you want them used across many translation units that will be linked later, you'd want a non-`static` declaration in a header without the constructor values, and a separate implementation file defining the variables with their values....

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the values inside a constructor.

```
somestructuretype{
   string alpha, bravo, charlie;

   somestructuretype(){
      alpha = "this is string A";
      bravo = "this is string B";
      charlie = "this is string C";
   };
};
```

Note however, you'll have to create a `somestructuretype` object before you use them. If you don't want that, declare them as `static`.